# How to apply spray-on polyurethane to a textured paint?

Tags: wood, paint, polyurethane

I am wanting to spray on coats of water-based polyurethane to a painted wood surface using a HVLP Spray Gun. The painted surface already has textured particles added into it to improve slip-resistance. I'm wanting to add polyurethane because I'm afraid that the texture will slowly chip away without a sealing coat on top.

I've read that you need to sand down the surface between each layer of polyurethane to allow for better adhesion, but I'm afraid that sanding the textured paint will ruin it. Any tips on how to resolve this?

Comment: You want to put a slippery surface on a no skid surface to keep it from wearing down??? The whole idea on no skid is the rough surface poly will be about the worst thing you can do in my opinion. I would be prepared to recoat in a few years if it wears through.

Comment: Hi Ed - I'm just worried about the anti-skid particles coming loose with use. Each time I take a shoe to scrape over a test sample, it chips off a significant amount of small anti-skid particles and the paint comes off and onto my shoe too. I want to reduce this as much as possible.

Comment: I guess you could try an overcoat but would think it will look worse if you do get a few coats on the high points will still break and the poly will haze or turn white where each fracture point is with just the paint it could be recoated.